# Symfony routing/URLs

Tags: symfony, url, routes, backend

I am making simple project where you can make your domain (like slack etc.), then you create projects inside of domain and tasks inside projects.

Iv'e made login/register system and form for adding domains when you're logged in.
Iv'e made relations between tables.
in domain table i have a field called url which is random 4 digit int.

I don't know how my link to **domain->project->task** should look like.
i was thinking about **/main/?k=1234 1234 1234** where each 4 digits are representing scheme mentioned above.

Question is: Should i do it like that or find some other way?

````
{
    /**
     * @Route("main", name="app_main")
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $domain = new Domain();
        $form = $this->createForm(DomainFormType::Class, $domain);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $User = $this->getUser()->getID();
            $domain->setUsers($User);
            $domain->setUrl(rand(100000, 999999));

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($domain);
            $entityManager->flush();
            }

        return $this->render('main.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "keys" are way too simple, you could end up with duplicates. If possible, simply use the primary key (id) of the domain/project/task. In that case you probably don't need the `$url` property anymore in these three entities.

But as you tried to come up with a more complex scheme, I suppose you want these urls to be accessible to anonymous users, without making them accessible to just anyone trying random ids in the URL.
If that's what you are trying to accomplish, consider using random strings instead of random integers. Here is an example of random string generation, which is actually used by Symfony to generate secure tokens:

```php
$entropy = 128;
$bytes = random_bytes($entropy / 8);
$randomString = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($bytes), '+/', '-_'), '=');
```

It returns an URL safe base64 encoded cryptographically secure pseudo-random string that does not contain "+", "/" or "=" which would need to be URL encoded. String length is `ceil($entropy / 6)`.

If you really need to use int keys, `rand()` is not cryptographically secure (meaning it is not as random as we would like it to be), use [random_int()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) instead.

Either way, consider making sure that you don't get duplicates entries and set those `url` fields to `unique` in your database.
If your "keys" are not very long, or if you want to handle a "one in a billion" case and avoid a database exception, you could also manually check for duplicates when you generate a random "url" (probably with `findOneBy()`) and generate another "url" if a match is found (e.g. do the generation + check in a `while` loop and break the loop if no match is found, then `setUrl($randomUrl)`)